# How to access promises from another service, AngularJS

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I have a promise in my service which comes from another service. I want to access the data directly.

This is (a tiny part) of my service:

```
  factory('CalculationFactory', function(SizeFromPipe){
     var input = {
       sizes: function(pipe_id){
         var sizesFromPipes = SizeFromPipe.getSizes(pipe_id);
         sizesFromPipes.then(function(val){
          console.log(val); //Is an object
          return val; 
         });
     }
     return input;
  }).
```

This is my "dataservice":

```
 factory('SizeFromPipe', function($resource, $q){
    return {
      getSizes:  function(pipe_id){
        var deffered = $q.defer();
        $resource('/api/sizes/fromPipe/:id', {'id':'@id'})
          .query({id:pipe_id},
          function(sizes){
            deffered.resolve(sizes);
          },
          function(response){
            deffered.reject(response);
          });

        return deffered.promise;
      }
    };
  })
```

I'd like to do this from my controller:

```
$scope.sizes = CalculationFactory.sizes(pipe_id)
```

I get undefined though.

Any ideas?

**Update**: Added the data service. I know I can access this with .then.. from controller. I'd really like to keep my controller clean so if it's possbile to take care of this in my model instead, that would be great.

Comment: did you return anything at the end of `factory('CalculationFactory'`?

Comment: are you sure that `CalculationFactory.input.sizes(pipe_id)` works? I think it should be `CalculationFactory.sizes(pipe_id)`

Comment: Ah, sorry. Fixed it. I have one layer more in my actual model.

Comment: I think we need to somehow customize the controller creation process to create the controller only when all dependencies are resolved. (I don't know how to do that yet)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I personally keep resource factory clean and instead using resolve in `$routeProvider`, and found the way to access scope variable through `$route.current.scope`. So, assigning right there.
and no code in controller, when route changes its automatically fetch response from server.

```
resolve: {
  anyname: function($route, Pipe) {
    Pipe.query($route.current.params, function(data) {
      $route.current.scope.some_variable = data;
    });
  }
}
```

resource

```
something.factory("Pipe", function($resource) {
  return $resource('/api/sizes/fromPipe/:id');
})
```

Answer (score 0):

Warning: This is all untested, and i'm quite unsure that it is the best possible solution. Wait for someone more professional if you want something bullet-proofed.

Although you want to do the right thing, you are still getting fooled by asynchronicity.

Maybe something like:

```
  factory('CalculationFactory', function(PipeCalculation, SizeFromPipe){
     var input = {
       sizes: function(pipe_id){
         return SizeFromPipe.getSizes(pipe_id);              
         });
     },
  }).

 // in controller
 CalculationFactory.input.sizes(pipe_id).then(function(promise){
     $scope.sizes = promise;   
 })
```

... will help.

There are a lot of ways to accomplish this, though. Could be helpful to see the code of PipeCalculation, too. Maybe you are overthinking / over complicating things.

Another Method would be to return a new promise

```
factory('CalculationFactory', function(PipeCalculation, SizeFromPipe){
     var input = {
       sizes: function(pipe_id){

           // Assume that $q is available
           var defer = $q.defer();

           SizeFromPipe.getSizes(pipe_id).then(function(promise){
             defer.resolve(promise);
           })

           return defer.promise;          
         });
     },
  }).
```