# Not able to lazily update a controller scope with a REST service - Angularjs

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I have basically created a cache in my `Angular` service.  If the `REST` call has already been made, the an array is returned, else it makes the `REST` call to get the needed info.  Here is my service:

```
define(function(require) {

var module = require('portal/js/services/app.services');

return module.factory('providerService', function($resource) {
  return {
    requestingProviders: [],
    getRequestingProviders: function() {
      var that = this;
      if(this.requestingProviders.length === 0) {
        this.getResource().search({
          role: 'REQUESTING_PROVIDER'
        }, function(data) {
          that.requestingProviders = data.providers;
          return that.requestingProviders;
        });
      } else {
        return that.requestingProviders;
      }
    },
    getResource: function() {
      return $resource('/api/v1/providers/:providerId', {providerId:'@id'}, {
        search: {
          method: 'GET',
          headers: {
            'RemoteUser': 'jhornsby',
            'Content-Type': 'application/json'
          },
          params: {
            limit: 2000,
            organizationId : '0001194'
          }
        }
      });
    }
  };
};
```

Here is an example of me accessing the service from a controller:

```
define(function(require) {
  var module = require('portal/js/controllers/app.controller');

  module.controller('AddPatientCtrl', function($scope, providerService) {
   $scope.providers = providerService.getRequestingProviders();
  };

  return module;
});
```

When the `REST` call returns, it does not update my `scope.providers` variable in my `controller`.  When I try to access it a 2nd time, then it works fine by accessing the array instead of calling out to the `REST` service.  WHy won't my `scope` update in my `controller` during the `REST` call?

Comment: Is getResource an angular service or it is independent from angular?

Comment: I updated the question.  `getResource` is defined right below the method I am calling.

Comment: Scope is not the model. It references the model. It is possible you are shadowing a scope. The issue is described here: https://github.com/angular/angular.js/wiki/Understanding-Scopes If this is the case, change providers to data.providers (data is an object) and see if it works.

Comment: as far as I noticed so far, AddPatientCtrl will get called only **Once** per route changes. So, if there is no changes, nothing will happens. I use $routeProvider resolve function instead - http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20903738

Comment: So i update my question. Where the search method defined? Is it part of your angular app?

Comment: so in the controller, change `scope.providers` to `scope.data.providers` and that will make it an object?

Comment: Yes, it is a basic `$resource`.  No third party stuff here at all.

Comment: I assume `search()` does not return anything.

Comment: I added the search functionality.  This was a large class I was trying to make the question more digestable

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The prpblem is that you are calling an async get method

You'll have to assign the $scope in a callback function from the service (or in this case the factory) to make sure that it will take the desired value.

As you have said, in the first time $scope is assined to something that has not been yet resolved but in subsequent calls that parameter is resolved so $scope will get the proper value.

I hope it helped.